# swift how to create completion handler for this function

Tags: swift

I am new to swift please suggest me how to create completion handler for this service function

```
func postRequest(router: Router, postData: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> ()) { ......
```

I am stuck here

```
ServiceLayer.postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { (<#Result<Int, Error>#>) in
            return ....
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Result` has `.success` and `.failure` cases so you can use this `Result` like ->

```swift
postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let value): 
        // Do something

    case .failure(let error): 
        // Do something
    }
}
```

---

**BONUS**

[Understanding Result Type in Swift 5](https://medium.com/@azamsharp/understanding-result-type-in-swift-5-387d5ef9f45e)

Comment: yes it did thanks also can you suggest the same for this one: getRequest<T: Codable>(router: Router, completion: @escaping (Result<[T], Error>) -> ()) {

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61010751/how-can-i-parse-the-resulting-class-of-this-service-request-in-swift-or-what-sho

Answer (score 1):

It's just asking you to give the closure argument a name. You can do this:

```
ServiceLayer.postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { result in
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ServiceLayer.postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { (response) in
            switch response{
                 case .success(let id):
                     print(id)
                     //do something with return id
                 case .failure(let error):
                    //error handle
            }
        }
```

more info [Result type tutorial](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/articles/161/how-to-use-result-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

There are already couple of correct answers. 
If you have 2 similar post functions with different callback. F.e

```
func postRequest(router: Router, postData: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Result<Int, Error>) -> Void) {}
func postRequest(router: Router, postData: [String: String], completion: @escaping (Error) -> Void) {}
```

Then you can specify the type in call like that:

```
ServiceLayer.postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { (result: Result<Int, Error>) in
}

ServiceLayer.postRequest(router: Router.register, postData: postData) { (error: Error) in
}
```